# How to query multiple IDs using Data Adapter and DataSet?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, dataset, dataadapter

I've got a set of unique IDs that belong to Users table, eg. 1478, 8906, 4677, etc. Now how do I get a DataSet back with full record set of these users using DataAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Id's in a string variable and comma delimited then you can do the following
for example if your are using SQL Server

```
SqlDataAdpater apd=new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Users where UserId in("+users+")",new sqlconnection("connection info")
DataSet ds=new DataSet()
adp.fill(ds)
```

where `users` is a variable which contains the list of `Id`'s in a comma-delimited format

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: You should **NEVER** build a SQL query by just concatenating together your statement. This opens the barn door to **SQL injection attacks** - a very very bad idea... use **parametrized queries** instead!

Comment: That's what I normally do; to filter by fields (columns) using ddls and other controls , but now I need it to loop through my list or set. Or the above solution makes sense too.

Comment: I was just missing ... in("+ @ +")" ...is that going to work in a query builder?

Comment: marc_s sorry i should have highlight it, didn't notice, as for the parameter thing, yeah you are right, it should be written like that.

Comment: Note you also have to be careful using the where id in (...) clause. If you don't know the number of potential id's being passed in - it can kill your performance.

Comment: it should not be more than 100 at any point, conn over the intranet, thousands of records, so this should be ok, shouldn't it ?...alright I did give it a go: and this is what it's turned to: (id IN ([ + @param + ])) ... haven's slept since yesterday, so apologies, I might be missing out something obvious here

Comment: (cast(id as varchar(20)) IN ( @param))
where @param is of type varchar, you have to cast because you will get an exception related to int and varchar

Comment: I set @param to String in DataSet's query properties. It worked now I rebooted PC and it no longer does. This is what I've got in query builder: SELECT Column1,Column2 FROM Table1 WHERE (CAST(id AS Varchar(20)) IN (@param )) ...

Comment: this returns NULL: WHERE (CAST(id AS Varchar(20)) IN (@param)), if multiple ids in string e.g. 5688,5689, if single (5688) it returns a single record